# Debugging Delphi com component in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, delphi, visual-studio-2012, com, regsvr32

I have a custom DLL written in Delphi, and it fails to load as a COM component. I ran regsvr32 with it, but now it fails to load with Visual Studio Interop.

[image: Delphi Interop Error]
.

I am quite amazed by this error because my colleagues got it working and it is compiled as a COM component. And that is confirmed by Dependency Walker:

[image: Dependency Walker].

I understand there is no tailor-made solution to this but do any of you have an idea where to start debugging on this error?

Comment: Could you try storing the dll in a path without space in any of the folder names? It may be silly, but I've known that to cause COM to not work in some cases.

Comment: It was a problem of a whole different genre. But the problem with the spaces I also encountered.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Turned out the delphi DLL had a hidden dependency on a delphi development DLL. I installed CodeSite (a delphi development tool, comparable to Log2Console) which installed the development DLL and made solved the issue.

Then I registered my DLL with regsvr32 and Visual Studio accepted my DLL. Which is a solution, but also worries me at the same time.

For others with the same problem. CodeSite is found at http://www.raize.com/DevTools/CodeSite/Default.asp

Comment: Hmm, logging logic in the release build of the DLL?

Comment: Yes, we will have a discussion about that over here ;)